# Why can't I upgrade scipy with pip?

Tags: scipy, pip

SciPy is available in version 0.19 ([link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy)). I have version 0.18.1:

```
$ python -c "import scipy;print(scipy.__version__)"
0.18.1
```

But when I want to upgrade it (with pip 9.0.1), nothing happens:

```
$ sudo -H pip install scipy --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scipy)
```

How can I upgrade scipy and why doesn't it work with pip?

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import scipy;print(scipy.__file__)"` ?

Comment: /home/moose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.pyc

Comment: Probably also interesting: Installing scipy in a virtual environment installs 0.19

Comment: I am not exactly sure of the full process but I believe that here the problem is that the scipy in `/usr/local` is not under the control of pip and it will thus not update it. What I see as possible solutions: remove the `/usr/local/` install of scipy or use the `-I` flag to pip (will ignore installed version, according to the doc).

Comment: `sudo -H pip install -I scipy --upgrade` does install scipy 0.19, but when I include scipy it is still 0.18.1

Comment: I removed the package with `sudo apt-get remove python-scipy` - it still imports scipy 0.18.1. Still from `'/home/moose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.pyc'`

Comment: Aaaah, `pip uninstall scipy` removed the user-installed version. Now it imports `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.pyc'`

Comment: And, is it the good one now?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Yes! Your hint with `scipy.__file__` helped me, thank you. Do you want to post an answer? Otherwise I would post a community wiki answer.

Comment: I am writing an answer. Beware though that you pip-installed scipy in a location that is normally under control of a package manager. This could cause issue with later updates. I usually install the recent or up-to-date version of a package in my home with the `--user` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of scipy that is actually imported with the output of

```
python -c "import scipy;print(scipy.__file__)"
```

Then, you can uninstall version that are not under control of pip or try to force the installation with the `-I` flag to pip that makes it ignore installed versions.